# Imported obj file is missing

Tags: modeling

I am struggling with some building obj and Collada files. I am currently using v3.1.2. So when I am importing Collada and obj files into the blender I am unable to see the file. These files were large building files.

Also, help me to get the texture with that. So that The files can be visible with the textures in blender software.

Comment: please attach a capture of your outliner once the import process is completed.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am not getting any object outliner in my window